# How to tell which derived class object called a base class function

Tags: c++

i have a base class called Person and 2 derived classes called Student and Teacher. the base class has a data member called RegistrationFee, which both derived classes use it. and there's a function in the base class which do something on this data member (registrationFee) but the task that the function does, depends on the type of the object that called the func. so i have to know that by which class object the function got called.
sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a [virtual function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) to override the behavior in each specific class. For example:

```
class Person
{
public:
    //pure virtual function, i.e a function that doesn't have an implementation
    virtual int registrationFee() = 0;
};

class Student : public Person
{
public:
    int registrationFee() override
    {
        //whatever logic implements this function
    }
};
```